# Multi-connected sum decomposition of $n$-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, handle-decomposition

A connected sum decomposition of a closed $n$-manifold $M^n$:
$M^n = M_1^n \# M_2^n$, is to view $M^n$ as two closed $M_1^n$ and $M_2^n$, joined
by a neck $I\times S^{n-1}$.

Similarly, a $k$-connected sum decomposition of a closed $n$-manifold $M^n$:
$M^n = M_1^n \#_k M_2^n$, is to view $M^n$ as two closed $M_1^n$ and $M_2^n$, joined
by $k$ necks, each has a form $I\times S^{n-1}$.

I like to know the reference is this "$k$-connected sum decomposition". Is there a classification of $n$-manifolds via the $k$-connected sum decomposition? Is there a classification of 3-manifolds via the $k$-connected sum decomposition?

Comment: For 3-manifolds, yes.  Your multi-connect-sum is usually just called "connect-sum" of arbitrarily many manifolds.  It is called the "prime factorization".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_decomposition_of_3-manifolds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a reference, but I think it's not too hard to see that $M_1 \#_k M_2 \approx M_1 \# X_k \# M_2$, where $X_k = (S^1 \times S^{n-1})^{\# (k-1)}$.  (Connected sum depends on choices of embedded disks, and so does $k$-connected sums; I'm assuming you want all $k$ pairs of disks to be isotopic.)  So decomposing using $k$-connected sum is not so different from decomposing using usual connected sum, except for some bookkeeping about extra summands of $S^1 \times S^{n-1}$.

The idea of this formula $M_1 \#_k M_2 \approx M_1 \# X_k \# M_2$ is that gluing the first neck gives $M_1 \# M_2 \approx M_1 \# S^n \# M_2$; the remaining $k-1$ necks may then be attached to the middle $S^n$ instead of between $M_1$ and $M_2$, each of which creates an $(S^1 \times S^{n-1})$-summand.